# How to load/refresh ngAfterViewInit after query params value changes on same component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am loading createComponent(this.queryparams) method ngAfterViewInit() event and passing the queryparams value in createComponent method. Depending upon the query params value I am loading Component dynamically.

But the component is loading once only on page load and when query param value is changing it is not loading the component.

How to refresh/load the ngAfterViewInit() on query param value changes?

Comment: You can subscribe route query parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subscribe to actvatedRoute params, and when params change, just simply reload the method where you use those params. Let‘s see that in action:

component.html:

```
***
constructor(){
 this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = params.id;
        this.name = params.name;
        this.ngAfterViewInit(); // or some other method where you are using those query parameters
    });
***
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I used this one (this._router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false; ) under constructor now it is working fine .

Comment: I want to load component dynamically on each step depends upon the contains value in SharedWizardComponent . How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
       this.createComponent(this.wizardData);
   }
```